# CHtml:button onclick event

Tags: php, jquery, yii

I'm trying to add an onlick event to my button. here is my code

```
 CHtml::button("Compare",
array('class'=>"btn btn-warning",'onclick'=>'js:var str = $.map($(\'input[name="checkbox_compare"]:checked\'), 
function(n, i){
return n.value;}).join(\',\'); 
if (isNotEmpty(str)) { window.location.href = "'.url('/compare/').'?ids="+str; } else { alert("Select atleast one"); }'))
```

the code works fine, but generates a html that looks like this

```
  <input class="btn btn-warning" onclick="js:var str = $.map($(&#039;input[name=&quot;checkbox_compare&quot;]:checked&#039;), 
function(n, i){
return n.value;
}).join(&#039;,&#039;); 
if (isNotEmpty(str)) { window.location.href = &quot;/wm/frontend/www/compare/?ids=&quot;+str; } 
else { alert(&quot;Select atleast one&quot;); }" name="yt0" type="button" value="Compare" />
```

still new to Yii, but was wondering if there is a better way / cleaner way to do this?

Comment: You could call javascript function instead onclick="yourfunction();"

Comment: yeah, but i have to put that in a JS file right? is there away with button? just like CactiveForm has `afterValidate` that can add the javascript into the view at the bottom of my page

Comment: Yes, you can add javascript in your view file using script tag but it will be good if you place it in js file.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a js file, I would do it like this:

```
<?php
    Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('myscript', '
    function myAwesomeFunction() {
        var myVar = 12;
        alert(myVar);
    }
    ', CClientScript::POS_END);

    echo CHtml::button("Compare", array('class ' => "btn btn-warning", 'onclick' => 'js:myAwesomeFunction()'));
?>
```